# How do I get a response based on two different IDs in my API?

Tags: entity-framework, api

```
public class Report
{
    [Key]
    public int ReportId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Subjects")]
    public int SubjectId { get; set; }
    public Subjects Subjects { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Teacher")]
    public int TeacherId { get; set; }
    public Teacher Teacher { get; set; }

   [ForeignKey("MarkType")]
    public int MarkTypeId { get; set; }
    public MarkType MarkType { get; set; }
}

public class Teacher
{
    [Key]
    public int TeacherId { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Required]
    public string FName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Required]
    public string LName { get; set; }

}

public class Student
{
    [Key]
    public int StudentId { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Required]
    public string FName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Required]
    public string LName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Grade")]
    public int GradeId { get; set; }
    public Grade Grade { get; set; }
}

public class Grade
{
    [Key]
    public int GradeId { get; set; }
    public int StudentGrade { get; set; }
}

public class Subjects
{
    [Key]
    public int SubjectId { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Required]
    public string SubjectName { get; set; }
}

public class Terms
{
    [Key]
    public int TermId { get; set; }

    public int Term { get; set; }
}

public class MarkType
{
    [Key]
    public int MarkTypeId { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(20)]
    [Required]
    public string TypeName { get; set; }

}

public class StudentMark
{
    [Key]
    public int StudentMarkId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Report")]
    public int ReportId { get; set; }
    public Report Report { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Student")]
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public Student Student { get; set; }

    public int Mark { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Terms")]
    public int TermId { get; set; }
    public Terms Terms { get; set; }

}
```

In the API I am making I want to have the ability to use two different IDs to get a more specific response.

```
var report = ReportDBContext.StudentMark
            .Include(p => p.Student.Grade).Include(p => p.Report)
            .Include(p => p.Terms).Include(a => a.Report.Subjects).Include(a => a.Terms)
            .Include(a => a.Report.MarkType).Include(a => a.Report.Teacher).ToList();
```

This allowed me to get StudentMark as well as it's related entities but I want to have the ability to use The student's Id and the Term's Id to get a student's marks for that term and all the subjects related to the student. I am a beginner to Web API so please let me know if I need to add more context.

Comment: Sure, no problem

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query by either `StudentId` or `TermId`, I suggest that you provide two different endpoints for these two different queries. Use LINQ [`Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.7.2) to check your conditions.

```
public StudentMark[] GetMarksByStudentId(int studentId) {
    return ReportDBContext.StudentMark
        /* .Include(...) */
        .Where(mark => mark.StudentId == studentId)
        .ToArray();
}

public StudentMark[] GetMarksByTermId(int termId) {
    return ReportDBContext.StudentMark
        /* .Include(...) */
        .Where(mark => mark.TermId == termId)
        .ToArray();
}
```

If you want to query by `StudentId` and `TermId` simultaneously, introduce a query object to encapsulate your parameters. You can test for multiple conditions in the `Where` clause with AND `&&`.

```
public StudentMark[] FindMarks(StudentMarkQuery query) {
     return ReportDBContext.StudentMark
            /* .Include(...) */
            .Where(mark => mark.StudentId == query.StudentId
                        && mark.TermId == query.TermId)
            .ToArray();
}
```

The `StudentMarkQuery` class is introduced so you can add additional parameters without changing the overall signature of the endpoint:

```
public class StudentMarkQuery {
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public int TermId { get; set; }
}
```